# how to get dark fill color in flot chart?

Tags: flot

Hi i have created line chart with multiple values But am not getting the fill color is dark.Some opacity is applying i guess.how to resolve that.
 my fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/v4y9e/3/`

`

```
    var DataSet20 = [ 
                        [new Date("2014/02/25").getTime(), 50],
                        [new Date("2014/03/11").getTime(), 150 ],
                        [new Date("2014/03/15").getTime(), 75 ],
                        [new Date("2014/03/22").getTime(), 140] ];

                var DataSet21 = [ 
                        [new Date("2014/02/25").getTime(),70],
                        [new Date("2014/03/11").getTime(), 250],
                        [new Date("2014/03/15").getTime(), 150 ],
                        [new Date("2014/03/22").getTime(), 180] ];


                var DataSet22 = [ 
                        [new Date("2014/02/25").getTime(), 100],
                        [new Date("2014/03/11").getTime(), 350 ],
                        [new Date("2014/03/15").getTime(), 190 ],
                        [new Date("2014/03/22").getTime(), 210] ];


                var newDate = new Date();
                    var day = newDate.getDay();
                    var date = newDate.getDate();
                    var setDate;
                    var ticArray = [];
                    for(var i = 0;i<5;i++){
                        if(i!=0){
                            setDate =newDate.setDate(date-day+1-7*i);
                            ticArray.push(setDate);
                        } else {
                            setDate =newDate.setDate(date-day+1);
                            ticArray.push(setDate);
                        }               
                    }

              $.plot($("#chart-revenue2"),[
                {  
                        label: "Search",
                        data: DataSet20,
                        color:'#94AACD',

                },
                { 
                        label: "Genre",
                        data: DataSet21,
                        color:"#D98445",
                        lines: {
                            fill: true,
                            lineWidth: 3,
                            }
                },{  

                        label: "New and Hot", 
                        data: DataSet22,
                        color:"#4598AE",
                    }] ,{
                xaxis: 
                    { mode: "time", 
                    min: ticArray[4],
                    max:ticArray[0],
                    timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
                    ticks: ticArray.reverse(),
                    minTickSize :30
                    }
                ,yaxis: {
                      min:0, max: 400,  tickSize: 50 
                    },
                     series: {
                       label: "Revenue",
                       lines: { 
                            show: true,                         
                            fill: true
                       },
                       shadowSize: 0
                   },
                   grid: {backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#f4f4f4"] }},
                    legend: {
                        show: true
                   }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the series 'fill' option, as described in the [Customizing the data series](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series) section of the docs.

Be aware that when you make the series opaque the top one will cover up the others.  I don't know what kind of data you're showing exactly, but you might want to consider the [stack plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/stacking).